# Осталась ли ошибочность в этом предложении

Tags: местоимение

Есть предложение с ошибкой:

> "Учитель предложил ученику ответить на вопросы по **своему** докладу".

Ученик исправил его так:

> "Учитель предложил ученику ответить на вопросы по его докладу".

На мой взгляд, ошибка так и осталась, поскольку двойственность не устранена. Важно знать еще кое-что: не действует ли в данном примере правило, гласящее о том, что местоимение заменяет **ближайшее** существительное. Мне кажется, что таким предложениям нельзя найти адекватной замены, не перелопачивая предложение полностью. Что вы думаете?

Comment: Учитель предложил ученику ответить на вопросы по его (ученика) докладу

Comment: мутное предложение, не ясно, кто чего и зачем хочет и по какой теме). Сложно предположить, что было дальше - ученик отказался отвечать? Напоминает анекдоты про Штирлица: "Штирлиц вытащил записку Бормана. Борман обиделся и полез обратно." Когда ученик окончил доклад, учитель предложил ему ответить на вопросы. Проблема фразы, что "доклад" начинает существовать в тексте из ничего, нет контекста чей он, может быть это доклад другого студента?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы упростил:

> Учитель предложил ученику ответить на вопросы по докладу.

Остальное будет понятно из контекста - учитель не пишет доклады.

Answer (score 0):

То, к чему относится местоимение понимается по смыслу. Вот два примера со словами с одинаковым числом и родом: ‟Василий собирался отправиться домой на мотоцикле, но он не завёлся”; ‟Мотоцикл этот был любимым для Василия, но на этот раз он не завёлся”. В обоих предложениях мы понимаем, что ‟он” относится к мотоциклу, так как Василий не может заводиться. (Я переставлял местами слова ‟Василий” и ‟мотоцикл”, чтобы дать понять, что нет такого правила, что местоимение относится к последнему слову.  )

В обоих ваших предложениях нет ошибки, потому что с контекстом там будет понятно, что к чему относится и чей доклад читать ученику.

Comment: С контекстом все будет понятно, это понятно. Вопрос чисто формальный, что может нам предложить великий и могучий для устранения двусмысленности.

Comment: Никаких. А зачем, если всё работает. Можно предположить, что род существует как раз для таких ситуаций, чтобы сократить количество ситуаций, когда отнесение слов понимается по смыслу.

Comment: Ну, почему же никаких, всегда можно явно пояснить кого имеют в виду учителя или ученика. См, например, мой старый комментарий. Зачем - из научного любопытства, не более.

Answer (score 0):

Штирлиц вытащил из сейфа записку Мюллера...

В моём понимании фраза мало того, что двусмысленная, так ещё и "учитель предложил ученику"...

Это какая-то попытка обойтись ограниченным словарным запасом и базовой(?) грамматикой, при этом создавая около тавтологические конструкции на пустом месте? Ведь вряд ли уборщица будет предлагать ученику. Давайте ещё напишем: "учитель учил ученика" или "ученик учится в школе".

А еще подоклад...

*Студенту/ученику было предложено защититься, ответив на вопросы к докладу.*

Вообще странная ситуация, что учитель предлагает ответить на вопросы. Как будто ученик мог сказать: нет мол, учитель, я не буду отвечать на ваши вопросы.

*Когда ученик окончил доклад, слушателям было предложено задать ему вопросы.*

*Когда ученик окончил свою речь, учитель задал ему дополнительные вопросы по теме доклада.*

Ох, я уже рассказывал этот анекдот, полгода прошло, а реакция такая же...